# how to remove the save button in odoo 10?

Tags: odoo-10

I need to remove or disable the save and cancel button in the purchase order module i used create="false" and edit="false" but it didn't work. Is there any solution to do it in another way?

Comment: you can simply enable debug mode then go to edit form view and remove button tag from view architecture.

Comment: i couldn't find the button name in the view file i think it's inherited from another view that i'm not able to reach

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right what you want is to hide a button that is default from odoo, right?

If so, you can do 2 thing via code inherit or use the menus of debug.

#### Via code

- Check if you have the model in the views
- If not add it to the **.xml**

To see how to inherit please check this link from [addons/l10n_be_invoice_bba/views/res_partner_view.xml](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/58ad37b17148cb3cec7f05af966982b19274631b/addons/l10n_be_invoice_bba/views/res_partner_view.xml) via github/odoo

This is another example of how to add invisible via code

[addons/base_gengo/wizard/base_gengo_translations_view.xml](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/651caf0f5913b1f8c0758664b55644d7d35f00a6/addons/base_gengo/wizard/base_gengo_translations_view.xml)

#### via menus with debug mode

Or enable debug on the settings or the add it on the URL and:

> Settings **-->** User Interface **-->** Views **-->** `Select your view` --> `add invisible to the item you want`

Comment: I couldn't understand what you exactly meant but i want to tell you that in the view file (purchase_views.xml) the code lines related to the the buttons save and discard are not mentioned. i think it's inherited and i couldn't find the lines that indicate this to modify or delete it, so is there any solution to find the file view that  purchase_views refers to to display those buttons?

Comment: This new question "How to inherit a button and modify it" has been answered here: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43346274/odoo-10-view-inherit-error)

Comment: Could you please say if that helped? if not please write a better description and in in case you followed any of this instructions in what you are not getting. Best regards @DhouhaSlaoui